# Delete Hierarchy (Like Outliner.delete with hierarchy checked) in 3d viewport?

Tags: keymap

In the outliner, you can now delete hierarchies.
Which, if you select a collection deletes the collection and objects/ collections nested within.
[image]

Is it also possible to activate this tool in a 3d viewport?

Comment: In the 3D viewport you can select the whole collection with Shift G

Comment: "*Is it also possible to activate this tool in a 3d viewport?*" No because an object may be in several different collections at the same time, even different scenes. In the viewport you can't unequivocally determine which of the arbitrary hierarchies to delete.

Comment: The 3d viewport doesn't have a concept of selected collection, only selected objects, so you'll have to define a custom operator that will fetch the active collection in the outliner, which defeats the purpose